# Parsing LocalTime with leap second

Tags: java, datetime, leap-second

I am trying to understand how to build a custom [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for my application. I basically need to handle time that are written like this **"HHMMSS.FFFFFF"**.

I was able to get 99% of it using:

```
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE;
public static final DateTimeFormatter MY_TIME;
static {
    MY_TIME = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
            .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendFraction(MICRO_OF_SECOND, 0, 6, true)
            .toFormatter().withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
}
```

I can process inputs just fine:

```
String text = "101530";
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(text, MY_TIME);
```

or even

```
String text = "070907.0705";
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(text, MY_TIME);
```

and

```
String text = "0000";
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(text, MY_TIME);
```

But for some reason I cannot make sense of the API for handling leap second so the following always fails for me:

```
String text = "235960";
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(text, MY_TIME);
```

How should I build my [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) so that leap second is handled ?

---

Update: I really like the `ResolverStyle.STRICT`, since it reject invalid inputs such as:

- "251213" or,
- "126100"

So I cannot use `ResolverStyle.LENIENT` in this case, I simply want the extra special case for leap second.

Comment: Could you use `ResolverStyle.LENIENT`? (that seems to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is of limited use for my users (editing of invalid time), I can handle this special case using simply:

```
if (text.length() >= 6 && "60".equals(text.substring(4, 6))) {
    String newText = text.substring(0, 4) + "59" + text.substring(6);
    return LocalTime.parse(newText, MY_TIME);
}
return LocalTime.parse(text, MY_TIME);
```

It seems this is a generally accepted hack:

- https://gist.github.com/dehora/9b2ce8bac22d1b37393d8b4f7c9eb7aa

Answer (score 4):

A local clock time showing leap second does not make much sense without also showing the calendar date and the timezone. Otherwise you don't know if the string to be parsed is really valid (the `java.time`-package will not help you to validate it) or is just meant in a lenient way (i.e. parsing "60" as next second).

### About the leap second capabilities of `java.time`:

`java.time` would indeed tolerate any dummy date in combination with a leap second although this is wrong in most cases. And the `DateTimeFormatter` only accepts the UTC-offset zero but not expressions like "2012-07-01T08:59:60+0900".

Furthermore: `java.time.Instant` cannot store the leap second information but throws it away. You can only [query the parser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parsedLeapSecond--) for a possible leap second flag. And then it is up to you what you want to do with this information.

Conclusion: This approach is fine for you if you want to ignore the leap second information but otherwise tolerate it in input.

### Alternatives:

If you are really interested in parsing, validating and evaluating possible leap seconds then I recommend to use my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J). But it does require a valid calendar date (leap seconds are inserted only on very few dates).

```
     ChronoFormatter<Moment> formatter = 
         ChronoFormatter.ofMomentPattern( 
             "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss XXX", 
             PatternType.CLDR, 
             Locale.ROOT, 
             ZonalOffset.UTC 
         )
     Moment m = formatter.parse("2012-07-01T08:59:60+09:00");

     // this conversion throws away the leap second
     Instant i = m.toTemporalAccessor();
```

For more informations, see also my article on [DZone](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjpvqvYna3YAhWMKVAKHaxJCxgQFgguMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdzone.com%2Farticles%2Fhow-watch-next-coming-leap&usg=AOvVaw1vW1bYI3hX6lYaJ27nHCL5).

Answer (score 2):

Relevant description from [java.time.Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) JavaDoc:

> [...] this Java API defines its own time-scale, the *Java Time-Scale*.
>   ...
>   Implementations of the Java time-scale using the JSR-310 API 
>   are not required to provide any clock that is sub-second accurate, 
>   or that progresses monotonically or smoothly. 
>   Implementations **are therefore not required** to actually perform 
>   the UTC-SLS slew or **to otherwise be aware of leap seconds**.
>   ...
>   The Java time-scale is used for all date-time classes. This includes Instant, LocalDate, LocalTime, OffsetDateTime, ZonedDateTime and Duration.

In short you should not expect `java.time` API to be aware of leap seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Leap second handling only works for `appendInstant`: see [DateTimeFormatter:parsedLeapSecond](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parsedLeapSecond--)

> Instant parsing handles the special "leap second" time of '23:59:60'.
>   Leap seconds occur at '23:59:60' in the UTC time-zone, but at other
>   local times in different time-zones. To avoid this potential
>   ambiguity, the **handling of leap-seconds is limited to
>   DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendInstant()**, as that method always parses
>   the instant with the UTC zone offset.

Comment: Are you suggesting I should prefix my string with a dummy date, and parse it using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` instead ?

Comment: @malat Yes, dummy dates are possible, see also my answer. `java.time` does not validate it. The only check is just to look for "23:59:60" (exactly these time components).