# Parse LocalDateTime with leap second

Tags: java, java-time

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime.parse("2016-12-31 23:59:60", formatter))
```

It throws an exception, but I think that was an actually correct datetime because it was a leap second year. Is there something I can do  to parse such string with standard Java libraries?

Edit:
In [Parsing LocalTime with leap second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009870/parsing-localtime-with-leap-second) they deal with a LocalTime. The problem is different: a LocalTime does not have information about the date, but LocalDateTime does, and the past leap seconds, like the one in the example, are well known.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the (Oracle) Java JVM know a leap second is occurring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984599/how-does-the-oracle-java-jvm-know-a-leap-second-is-occurring)

Comment: Given that `LocalDateTime.getSecond()` is documented as "the second-of-minute, from 0 to 59" I strongly suspect java.time doesn't cater for leap seconds.

Comment: "I think that was an actually correct datetime because it was a leap second year". Why?  There is no consistent convention for handling this even if it were supported.

Comment: @possum what do you mean by "there no consistent convention"? The "23:59:60" convention is properly standardized, it's just that many applications don't know how to deal with it because their programmers were not fully informed about leap seconds. See https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/52354616/CCTF_UTC_presentation.pdf/0a8f0954-7c00-9142-8da2-f4221c7e0269

Comment: Yes.  You've cited *a* convention.  You might as well say UTC and the Gregorian calendar is all there is.

Comment: Well, with methods like `Clock.systemUTC()` and `ZoneOffset.UTC`, you might be forgiven for believing Java follows UTC convention.

Comment: If you use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT)` it will parse without an exception.  However, the returned value will be midnight of the following day, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: *I think that was an actually correct datetime because it was a leap second year.* Whether it is correc, depends on time zone, and Java can’t guess what time zone you intended, so refuses to make that judgement for you. That said, java.time offers very little support for leap seconds.

Comment: Take a look at [`DateTimeFormatter.parsedLeapSecond()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parsedLeapSecond()).

Answer (score 4):

The class `LocalDateTime` represents a date and time without reference to a time zone. A leap second always occurs at midnight UTC (+00:00). As such, a leap second can occur in the middle of the day in some parts of the world, not necessarily at midnight. Given this, `LocalDateTime` cannot possibly parse a leap second as the time zone offset is not known.

A leap second can be parsed when parsing an `Instant`:

```
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendInstant().toFormatter();
  TemporalAccessor parsed = formatter.parse(str);
  Instant instant = parsed.query(Instant::from);
  if (parsed.query(DateTimeFormatter.parsedLeapSecond())) {
    // validate and handle leap-second
  }
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parsedLeapSecond--) for more details.

Furthermore, [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) has support for the [UTC and TAI timescales](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/scale/package-summary.html) with leap seconds.

Finally, bear in mind that it is likely there will be no more leap seconds. The relevant standards bodies appear to have decided to put the whole idea in the bin. (I was aware this might happen when designing `java.time.*`, and strongly maintain that minimal handling of leap seconds is the right design for `java.time.*`.)

Comment: The code in this answer works if you modify the string from the question like `String str = "2016-12-31 23:59:60".replace(' ', 'T') + 'Z';` (better if you can get a string in ISO 8601 format from the outset, though).

Answer (score 1):

## `LocalDateTime`

The [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class has no concept of offsets, time zones, or [Leap Second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). This class does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. This class assumes every day is exactly 24 hours of 60 minutes each, of exactly 60 seconds each.

So asking `LocalDateTime` to parse a moment with a Leap Second is nonsensical.

## *Java Time-Scale*

Modern Java uses the *Java Time-Scale* defined in the Javadoc of the [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class.

Basically, this approach ignores Leap Second. This accomplishes the goal of keeping the clock in accord with the calendar. This approach works well for conventional business apps.

In accordance with this approach, the `Instant` class will parse your second of `60` as a second of `59`.

```
Instant.parse( "2016-12-31T23:59:60Z" ).toString()
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/P80ccK).

> 2016-12-31T23:59:59Z

For more discussion, see the Javadoc, and see [*How does the (Oracle) Java JVM know a leap second is occurring?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30984599/642706)

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

If you really need to work in a Leap Second conscious way, consider the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library.

That library [offers a time scale](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/scale/package-summary.html) that includes leap seconds. This includes a [`UtcInstant`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/scale/UtcInstant.html) class to represent an instantaneous point on the time-line measured in the UTC time-scale with leap seconds.